# Oracle database : How to get username used to connect to Oracle database using JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, listener

I wish to know whether Oracle logs the username used for the Oracle connection using JDBC in some log file.

From direct Oracle connection, I see the username getting logged in the listerner.log :

```
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<service_name>)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SESSION)(METHOD=BASIC)(RETRIES=120)(DELAY=5))(CID=(PROGRAM=sqlplus)(HOST=<host>)(USER=<username>)))
```

whereas for jdbc connections, I dont see the username:

```
 (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=<service_name>)(SERVER=DEDICATED))
```

Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: Is there a reason that you want the (fixed) username in the listener.log?  Normally, if you want to record this sort of thing, you'd enable auditing of connections in the database.

Comment: you could execute a query - "select user from dual"